# Storage space efficiency for scraping data over period of time python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, storage, google-cloud-storage

I want to store data regarding loan rates for assets on an exchange. The data is collected by using [this API call](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnLoanOrders&currency=BTC)

It is unknown how frequently the data changes. My original plan was to query the API every second and if new_data != previous_data then the new_data is stored.

It seems that the data is around 5kb in size, say the data changes every 10 seconds that means in one year:

total_required_storage_space = 5 * 6 * 60 * 24 * 365 = 15,768,000 KB = 15.04 GB

However if the data changes every second then this will be 150GB.

Could anyone comment on how I could make this more efficient ? For my computer this is quite a lot of space. Eventually I would like to have this running on a server, does any one have a good guide for beginners on how to do this? maybe this kind of storage space isn't a lot for say an AWS or some similar cloud service?

Comment: How are you currently storing it?

Comment: Can you specify some what will the access patterns will be? Namely, who will access the data for reading? How frequently is it going to be accessed? What queries you want to run on this data? How fast those queries need to be answered?

Comment: 150GB a year isn't really a big deal with space. Including some transfer costs that could go in S3 for about $50 a year

Comment: But in order to know if S3 is appropriate, we need to know how the data is going to be accessed. If it's just for archiving purposes, you could store in Glacier as well. If it's needed for really fast and frequent access, then S3 may not be fast enough.

Comment: @AdiLevin S3 is a default AWS "storage" option.  I don't think we have the time to list all the possible storage options here.  Even if the OP had given more access/query/speed requirements there would still be several answers.  Probably I should vote to close as "too broad"

Comment: It's broad indeed, but if he gives some more details then we can help him, don't you think?